# What are the eigenvalues of this matrix? Is it orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is this orthogonal? What are the eigenvalues?

I think it's orthogonal because $A * A^t$ is the identity matrix.

What are the eigenvalues though? CAn someone show me how to obtain them clearly?

Comment: You are right on its orthogonality. Now remark that your matrix is almost in diagonal form. Can you see how to do row operations to make it diagonal?

Comment: Certainly $1$ is an eigenvalue and since the matrix has determinant $1$ and is orthogonal, the others are $\zeta$ and $\zeta^{-1}$ where $|\zeta|=1$. From trace, $1=1+\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$.

Comment: @Angina Seng  I don't understand how could you say $1$ is an eigenvalue without any calculation,, is there any trick which I missed? That given matrix implies,, only det is $1$ , trace is $1$ , and modulus of each eigenvalue is $1$. So, my question, how could you say, and what is the trick?

Comment: @Alearner I saw that $\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ was an eigenvector.

Comment: @Angina Seng thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is orthogonal. The eigenvalues are $\pm i,1$. Try solving the equation $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$. Using @Angina Seng's method is faster.

Comment: My book says > a matrix is orthogonal if transposition gives the inverse of A. This doesn't appear to be teh case here

Comment: @Jwan622 It seems to me that the transpose of $A$ is its inverse.